# Solution of linear equation with variables

Tags: vector-spaces

For what values of a and b the following system of linear equations has

2x + 3y + 5z = 9

7x + 3y - 2z = 8

2x + 3y + az = b

a) no solution.
b) a unique solution.
c) an infinite number of solutions.

[I have found the properties of a and b as (a=5, b!=9) for no solution by its determinant. I have tried to find the others but couldn't find a way to write them in logic considering there are two variables. Am I going to write like if a=... then b=... or is there an other way? Is it going to be a=5 b!=9 for a) and a=5 b=9 for c) ?][I am mostly sucked with finding the unique solution set.]

Answer (score 0):

The system has a unique solution if and only if the determinant of the matrix of coefficients is non-zero. In all other cases, it has either no solution or infinitely many solutions. To distinguish the two, find the images of $$\left(\array{1\\0\\0}\right),\left(\array{0\\1\\0}\right),\mbox{ and } \left(\array{0\\0\\1}\right)$$ under (the linear map corresponding to) the matrix of coefficients. There are infinitely many solutions exactly when you can write $$\left(\array{9\\8\\b}\right)$$ as a linear combination of those image vectors, otherwise there are no solutions.

Comment: When a=5 the determinant is zero therefore no solution but when b=9, does it still count as no solution because of the determinant or can we say unique solution because 0 = 0 in the given values

Comment: The row equivalet form of the matrix = R1(1, -6, -17, -19), R2(0, 15, 39, 47), R3(0, 0, a-5, b-9)

Comment: Why would there be a unique solution? You're trying to solve the whole system, not just one dimension of it. 

And, again, the determinant being zero does **not** mean that there is no solution. It means that either their is no solution, *or* there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Your last sentence was the answer which I was waiting to confirm my question. And for the first sentence, it asks me the values of a and b such that system has unique solution.